# Merge N lists by randomly picking elements at each index

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, random

I have a bajillion paired lists, each pair of equal size.  I want to "merge" each by picking a random element from each index, but my current implementation is very slow - *even* when multiprocessing.  (FWIW, my code does need to be threadable).

```
def rand_merge(l1, l2):
    newl = []
    for i in range(len(l1)):
        q = random.choice([l1, l2])
        newl.append(q[i])
    return newl
```

Pretty basic, but running it on 20k lists of sizes ~5-25, it takes crazy long - I assume it's random.choice gumming up the works.  But I've also tried other versions of random, like creating a string of 0's and 1's to refer to, no go.

EDIT:
More clarity: It's a Genetic Algorithm designed to write sentences by matching up against a corpus.  The lists in question are sentences split by word.  The GA is "merging" winning fitness "parents" into children, each of which are a merging of the two parent sentences' "genes."
That means that the "lists" do need to match up, and can't pull from a larger list of lists (I don't think).

Here some code...

```
from multiprocessing import Pool as ThreadPool
import random

def offspring(parents):
    child = []
    p1 = parents[0].split(' ')
    p2 = parents[1].split(' ')
    for i in range(min(len(p1), len(p2))):
        q = random.choice([p1, p2])
        child.append(q[i])
    child = ' '.join([g for g in child]).strip()
    return child

def nextgen(l): #l is two lists of previous generation and grammar seed
    oldgen = l[0][:pop] # Population's worth of previous generation
    gramsent = l[1] # this is the grammar seed
    newgen = []
    newgen.append(tuple([oldgen[0][0], oldgen[0][0]]))  # Keep the winner!
    for i in range(len(oldgen) - len(oldgen)//4):
        ind1 = oldgen[0][0] # paired off against the winner - for larger pools, this is a random.sample/"tournament"
        ind2 = oldgen[i][0]
        newgen.append(tuple([ind1, ind2]))
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=8)
    newgen = pool.map(offspring, newgen)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

The populations and generations can get into high numbers together, and each sentence runs through.  Since posting the question originally, troubled that it was taking so long for each generation to roll by, I discovered (head-scratcher for me) that the long processing times actually have (almost) nothing to do with the "population" size or number of lists.  It was taking ~15 seconds to mutate each generation.  I upped the population from 50 to 50000 and the generations went from 15 seconds to 17 or so.  So the slowness is apparently hiding elsewhere.

Comment: You say "is very slow - even when multiprocessing" what exactly have you done in regards to multiprocessing/multithreading? Have you tried a combination of async/multithreading? An example of code that your not satisfied with in regards to multiXYZ would be very helpful so others don't offer examples you have already tried.

Comment: Can you give a small example?

Comment: I found the slowdown - it wasn't the function; it was that every time I call pool.join(), everything outside of __main__ gets called, and there was a lot of file-loading setup.  Setup that, unfortunately, I can't do inside of main, so I have to drop the multiprocessing module (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try merging all 20,000 lists at once, instead of two at a time.

```
from itertools import zip_longest
from functools import partial
import random

lists = [l1, l2, ...]

idxvals = map(partial(filter, None), itertools.zip_longest(*lists))
newl = [random.choice([*i]) for i in idxvals]
```

Since you want to pick a random element at each index, it makes sense to chose from all 20k lists at once instead of 2 at a time.

---

```
>>> lists = [[1, 2, 3], [10], [20, 30, 40, 5]]
```

`zip_longest` will zip to the longest list, filling missing values with `None`.

```
>>> list(itertools.zip_longest(*lists))
[(1, 10, 20), (2, None, 30), (3, None, 40), (None, None, 5)]
```

These Nones will need to be filtered out before the choose step. `filter` will help with that.

```
>>> f = partial(filter, None)
>>> list(map(list, map(f, itertools.zip_longest(*lists))))
[[1, 10, 20], [2, 30], [3, 40], [5]]
```

It should be clear what I'm trying to do. The ith index of the output contains those elements present at `l[i]`, for every `l` in `lists`.

Now, iterate over `idxvals` and choose:

```
>>> idxvals = map(f, itertools.zip_longest(*lists))
>>> [random.choice([*i]) for i in idxvals]
[10, 30, 3, 5]
```

Comment: I should have been more explicit that the lists do need to "pair off" - they're sentences sharing an underlying grammar.  The reason they *can* pair off at all is because they'll share a structure, e.g., of "Noun", "Verb", "Noun" - then they swap nouns and verbs, go back through a scoring rubric, and on and on.  This is all iterating through a massive corpus, however, so it must be fast.  I think I discovered that my speed is from a different issue, however.

Comment: @Xodarap777 sigh..., I see.

Comment: I did find a way to adapt this (it works if I set up lists of equivalent length first).